# STM32h7 as spi slave only

Tags: c, arm, stm32, spi

Im moving my project code from stmf407 to stm32h743
and i have stucked with spi. First of all stmh743 has
many more registers and it also lack some of them like RXONLY register in CR1.
What im trying to do its receive 19bytes from the master,the master is a complete device and i cant control it. The clock speed of the master is around 20nanoseconds. My previous project in stmf407 catching the data perfectly.

STM32F407 spi code:

```
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
 {

SPI1 parameter configuration*/
hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_SLAVE;
hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES_RXONLY;
hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
_Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }
 }
```

```
static void ReadSpi(void)
    
{       
RxSPI1 = 0;
MX_SPI1_Init();
GPIOA->MODER = 0xAA809910;
SPI1->CR1 |= 0x40;  
RxCounter = 0;
    while(RxCounter <20){

 

    while (!(hspi1.Instance->SR  & SPI_FLAG_RXNE))

         ;
       
        RxSPI = hspi1.Instance->DR;
                
        
// now you have 8 SPI clock cycles to do something with the data
if (RxSPI != 0xFF )
{
    RxTable[RxCounter++] = RxSPI;  

}
}

      
return;
```

STM32H743 CODE:
INIT FUNCTIONS:

```
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Supply configuration update enable
  */
  HAL_PWREx_ConfigSupply(PWR_LDO_SUPPLY);
  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE3);

  while(!__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_VOSRDY)) {}
  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 24;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = 2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = 2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLRGE = RCC_PLL1VCIRANGE_3;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLVCOSEL = RCC_PLL1VCOWIDE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLFRACN = 0;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D3PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D1PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB3CLKDivider = RCC_APB3_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_APB1_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_APB2_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB4CLKDivider = RCC_APB4_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{
hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_SLAVE;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES_RXONLY;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 0x0;
  hspi1.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.NSSPolarity = SPI_NSS_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi1.Init.FifoThreshold = SPI_FIFO_THRESHOLD_01DATA;
  hspi1.Init.TxCRCInitializationPattern = SPI_CRC_INITIALIZATION_ALL_ZERO_PATTERN;
  hspi1.Init.RxCRCInitializationPattern = SPI_CRC_INITIALIZATION_ALL_ZERO_PATTERN;
  hspi1.Init.MasterSSIdleness = SPI_MASTER_SS_IDLENESS_00CYCLE;
  hspi1.Init.MasterInterDataIdleness = SPI_MASTER_INTERDATA_IDLENESS_00CYCLE;
  hspi1.Init.MasterReceiverAutoSusp = SPI_MASTER_RX_AUTOSUSP_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.MasterKeepIOState = SPI_MASTER_KEEP_IO_STATE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.IOSwap = SPI_IO_SWAP_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

STM32H743 READ SPI FUNCTION:

```
static void ReadSpi(void)
    
{       
    

RxSPI1 = 0;
MX_SPI1_Init();
GPIOA->MODER = 0xAA809910;
SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CFG2_SSM;
SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SSI;
SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE;
RxCounter = 0;
    while(RxCounter <20){

 

    while (!(hspi1.Instance->SR  & SPI_FLAG_RXP))

         ;

        RxSPI = hspi1.Instance->RXDR;
                
        
// now you have 8 SPI clock cycles to do something with the data
if (RxSPI != 0xFF )
{
    RxTable[RxCounter++] = RxSPI;  

}
}

     
return;
}
```

So the line where we are waiting before catch the data in stm32f4 is
    `while (!(hspi1.Instance->SR  & SPI_FLAG_RXNE))`

and in stm32h743:
`while (!(hspi1.Instance->SR  & SPI_FLAG_RXP))`
the flag names are diffrent but i gues its ok.
here is the registers initialized and stmf32h743 waiting to catch the data.
[stm32h743 spi registers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TdRQ.png)
f4:
[stm32f407 spi registers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsBaY.png)

and this is the data im catching, please note that i cant control the master, all i can do its power on or power off.
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvRU7.png)

while f4 working fine, while h7 just stacked here `while (!(hspi1.Instance->SR  & SPI_FLAG_RXP))` , . What am i missing?